# Kendo ui kendoSortable not working

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I'm using kendo ui to create some grids. The code example bellow is the one that drived me into my implementation. I faced a bug during the development and I tried some workarounds but none of them worked.

http://dojo.telerik.com/AsUDo/14

Here's the problem: 
I need to create a grid with sortable behaviour (in the whole tr).

The whole line gets sortable only when I comment this line:

```
//ignore: "TD, input".
```

But then if I change the Product Name and then click in Unit Price, for instance, the text in the Product Name field is set to the previous value. It just doesn't get updated.

If I use the

```
ignore: "TD, input"
```

attribute though, the fields get updated whenever I type the Product Name and then change the Unit price or change any other field, but the only sortable column I get is the one with the template and that doesn't meet the requirement that my client asked.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sortable mousedown interferes with the cell save order of events, so when you edit the row and click off to another cell, the sortable events "kill" the editing events and your change is lost.

If you change your sortable filter to

```
filter: ">tbody >tr:not(.k-grid-edit-row)",
```

This "disables" the sortable events on the currently edited row so that the editing events can complete.

The downside is that if you want to sort/drag the row being edited, you must first click off the row(so that it is no longer the .k-grid-edit-row) and then go back and drag that row.

This is how I have my sortable grids set up and I just live with the downside...or you live with using a sort handler instead of allowing the whole row to be dragged.

You may be able to play around with the filter to overcome my downside, but I have not been able to and in the grand scheme of things, there are more important things to spend time on...i.e. try to get the client to relax the not-that-important requirement.